# Tukey test results displayed on geom_boxplot with facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, tukey

I am trying to generate 6 boxplots displaying Fish Abundances of 3 different sites displayed for each site between 2 seasons separately using faced_grid.

I want to add Tukey HSD results  on each single boxplot, but when I try, I always get the results of the dry season displayed.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: I'm sure we _could_ help you out if we had your data to test and verify possible solutions. Could you edit your question to include the output from `dput(Indices)` please? Without this, we cannot run your code.

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron,  I just did. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by `Season` too when building the labels for the plot (the `Tk`) data frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(multcompView)
library(ggpubr)

anova <- aov(Abundance ~ Site, data = Indices)
tukey <- TukeyHSD(anova)
cld <- multcompLetters4(anova, tukey)

Tk <- group_by(Indices, Season, Site) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Abundance), 
            quant = quantile(Abundance, probs = 0.75)) %>%
  mutate(cld = cld$Site$Letters[Site])

ggplot(Indices, aes(Site, Abundance)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Season, alpha = Site)) +
  theme_test()+
  facet_grid( ~ Season) +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.3, 0.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E08B00", "steelblue3"))+
  stat_compare_means(method = "anova", label.y = -0.3)+ 
  geom_text(data = Tk, aes(x = Site, y = quant, label = cld), size = 4,
            nudge_y = -4000) +
  guides(alpha = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "black")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! but there is still something not right with the letters. It should be for dry season: Elalab: ab, Malafo: a, Cafine: b. Rainy season= Elalab: a, Malafo: a, Cafine: a. Do u have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

All that was missing was the inclusion of the Season factor in the ANOVA and of course its interaction with Site. In addition, this allows us to study the interactions in Tukey's test. Basically, what you were asking for was to be able to group the observations according to homogeneous groups taking into account both factors simultaneously: Site and Season.

```
  library(tidyverse)
  library(multcompView)
  library(ggpubr)
  
  # This is a 2-way ANOVA with interactions Site * Season
  anova <- aov(Abundance ~ Site * Season, data = Indices)
  summary(anova)
  tukey <- TukeyHSD(anova)
  print(tukey)
  cld <- multcompLetters4(anova, tukey) # includes interactions!
  print(cld)
  
  Indices<-as.data.frame(Indices)
  Tk <- group_by(Indices, Site,Season) %>%
    summarise(mean=mean(Abundance), quant = quantile(Abundance, probs = 0.75)) %>%
    arrange(desc(mean))
  cld <- as.data.frame.list(cld$`Site:Season`)
  Tk$cld <- cld$Letters
  print(Tk)
  
  
  #creating the boxplots for each site, separated for each season
  bp1<-ggplot(Indices, aes(Site, Abundance)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Season, alpha = Site)) +
    theme_test()+
    facet_grid( ~ Season) +
    scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.3, 0.9),
                         guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "black"))) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E08B00", "steelblue3"))+
    stat_compare_means(method = "anova", label.y = -0.3)+ # Add global p-value
    geom_text(data = Tk, aes(x = Site, y = quant*1.7, label = cld), size = 5)
  
  bp1
```

[image: Boxplot 2 factors interactions with homogeneous subgroups letters]

However, you should be careful with the interpretation of these homogeneous subsets, they may include combined levels that you have no interest in comparing (e.g. "Cafine Dry is similar to Elalab Rainy"). Think about whether you need to tell this grouping or whether you need to tell something else about the interaction: What happens in rainy seasons at each site? Is the pattern the same or is it different? These questions will help you to tell the results of the interaction. The letters should serve as a "pointer" for a clear explanation of a paragraph.

Comment: Hi Jose, thanks for the explanation. What I actually did, was to compute the Tukey HSD test separately for two subdatasets of Indices: "Indicesdry" and "Indicesrainy". But I plotted the dataset "Indices" using ggplot to show both seasons separately using the "Indices" dataset. Is there a way to get both Tukey Tests shown onto the plot using ggplot?

Comment: If you have those results  in some other object you can put them into the Tk object. But TukeyHSD(x) requires x to be a fitted model, with those two factors you should have the results I've given you in the script. Also, in the graph we are visually seeing both Seasons simultaneously and it is clear that there is a "Dry" level that is similar to other "Rainy" levels. You should not use different letters for this that we all see in the graph.

Comment: Hi José, thanks so much for the explanation. It's a little confusing for me. I don't really have interest in comparing this interaction sitexseason for the entire dataset. As you said, I don't wish to compare CafineDry with ElalabRainy. But what I would want to test is the effect of Site for each season separately. Basically, it means I need to create two separate plots per season instead of showing them at the same time? Is that it? So I'd have two one-way ANOVAs and two Tukey tests instead of combining both into one plot?

Comment: When you are interested in studying the effect of two factors, it is obvious that if there is an interaction effect between them, then it is no longer necessary to explain the effect of each of them separately. If in your case there if there was a Site effect but there was also an interaction effect, then the Site effect would not be the same for all Seasons. You can see in the graph in my answer. The "Cafine" and "Elalab" indices are different in the two Seasons.

Comment: Of course, you might want to check the significance of the main and interaction effects in the ANOVA table.